# How to convert an input into a method that the program will understand

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm currently working on my homework about client and server topic:
I created a class called `VehileRequest.java` which will take three variables (year, make, model) from `Client.java` and pass them to `Server.java` then the `Server` will get information from `VehicleRespone.java` and display the information about price, miles vv...

As I understand, the program didn't recognize the request that pass to the respond file.

I got stuck at passing the Request to Response so that the Response will understand.  Any help please. thank you

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class VehicleResponse {
    private VehicleRequest request;
    private int milesOnVehicle;
    private int price;
    private int numberOfSeats;
    private int numberOfDoors;
    private String[] options;

    @JsonIgnore
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    public static String toJSON(VehicleResponse vehicle) throws Exception {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(vehicle);
    }
    
    public static VehicleResponse fromJSON(String input) throws Exception{
        return objectMapper.readValue(input, VehicleResponse.class);
    }
    
    protected VehicleResponse() {}
    
    public VehicleResponse(VehicleRequest request, int milesOnVehicle,int price, int numberOfSeats, int numberOfDoors,String[] options) {
        this.request=request;
        this.milesOnVehicle=milesOnVehicle;
        this.price=price;
        this.numberOfSeats=numberOfSeats;
        this.numberOfDoors=numberOfDoors;
        this.options=options;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Vehicle request:[miles=%d, price=%d, number of seats=%d,number of doors=%d, option='%s']",
                milesOnVehicle,price,numberOfSeats,numberOfDoors,options);
    }

    public VehicleRequest getRequest() {return request;}
    public int getMilesOnVehicle(){return milesOnVehicle;};
    public int getPrice(){return price;}
    public int getNumberOfDoors() {return numberOfDoors;}
    public int getNumberOfSeats() {return numberOfSeats;}
    public String[] getOptions() {return options;}

    public void setRequest(VehicleRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    public void setMilesOnVehicle(int milesOnVehicle) {
        this.milesOnVehicle = milesOnVehicle;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setNumberOfSeats(int numberOfSeats) {
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
    }

    public void setNumberOfDoors(int numberOfDoors) {
        this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
    }

    public void setOptions(String[] options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

Here is the VehicleRequest file

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class VehicleRequest {
    private int year;
    private String make;
    private String model;

    @JsonIgnore
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static String toJSON(VehicleRequest vehicle) throws Exception {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(vehicle);
    }
    public static VehicleRequest fromJSON(String input) throws Exception{
        return objectMapper.readValue(input, VehicleRequest.class);
    }
    protected VehicleRequest() {}

    public VehicleRequest(int year, String make, String model) {

        this.year = year;
        this.make =make;
        this.model=model;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Vehicle: [year=%d, make='%s', model='%s']",
                year,make,model);
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public String getMake(){return make;}
    public String getModel(){return model;}

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setMake(String make){
        this.make=make;
    }
    public void setModel(String model){
        this.model=model;
    }
}
```

Here is the Server

```java
public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public void start(int port) throws Exception {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            VehicleRequest request = VehicleRequest.fromJSON(inputLine);
            VehicleResponse response = new VehicleResponse(request,10000,12000,5,4, null);
            out.println(VehicleResponse.toJSON(response));
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        try {
            server.start(4444);
            server.stop();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the client

```java
public class Client {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public void startConnection(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public VehicleRequest sendRequest() throws Exception {
        out.println(VehicleRequest.toJSON(new VehicleRequest(2008,"Honda","Civic")));
        return VehicleRequest.fromJSON(in.readLine());
    }

    public void stopConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        try {
            client.startConnection("127.0.0.1", 4444);
            System.out.println(client.sendRequest().toString());
            client.stopConnection();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I got the result was

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "request" (class edu.sdccd.cisc191.template.VehicleRequest), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "model", "year", "make"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"request":{"year":2008,"make":"Honda","model":"Civic"},"milesOnVehicle":10000,"price":12000,"numberOfSeats":5,"numberOfDoors":4,"options":null}"; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: edu.sdccd.cisc191.template.VehicleRequest["request"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:855)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1212)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1604)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1582)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:299)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:156)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4482)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3402)
    at edu.sdccd.cisc191.template.VehicleRequest.fromJSON(VehicleRequest.java:17)
    at edu.sdccd.cisc191.template.Client.sendRequest(Client.java:32)
    at edu.sdccd.cisc191.template.Client.main(Client.java:44)
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for `VehicleRequest`? Additionally, can you please add the relevant code to "when I ran the program"? Thanks.

Comment: please add also the entire stacktrace

Comment: I see no server or client code here

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website. I just upload every thing I have rn. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `VehicleRequest.fromJSON(in.readLine());` you are trying to parse whatever it is the input, which seems to be:

```json
{
   "request":{
      "year":2008,
      "make":"Honda",
      "model":"Civic"
   },
   "milesOnVehicle":10000,
   "price":12000,
   "numberOfSeats":5,
   "numberOfDoors":4,
   "options":null
}
```

However, you are expecting this to be parseable to `VehicleRequest` which is not possible because it contains only 3 parameters and not all that. Either you parse this as `VehicleResponse` as follows:

```java
VehicleResponse.fromJSON(in.readLine());
```

Or you change the input to be something that can be parsed to `VehicleRequest`:

```json
{
    "year":2008,
    "make":"Honda",
    "model":"Civic"
}
```

---

If I am understanding your code correctly you are trying to make communication between `Client` and `Server`. In that case, you will need to change your `Client` code:

```java
public class Client {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public void startConnection(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
        clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    }

    public VehicleResponse sendRequest() throws Exception {
        out.println(VehicleRequest.toJSON(new VehicleRequest(2008,"Honda","Civic")));
        return VehicleResponse.fromJSON(in.readLine());
    }

    public void stopConnection() throws IOException {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        try {
            client.startConnection("127.0.0.1", 4444);
            System.out.println(client.sendRequest().toString());
            client.stopConnection();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh no. I literally put VehicleRequest instead of VehicleRespond. Thank you for your help. It work now.

Comment: Awesome @Tobi! If it works now, please consider upvoting it and accepting it as the answer so that your question can be "closed" and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: I can't vote yet, it need 15 reputation but thanks a lot

Comment: Now you have 31 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although [João Dias already solved your lapse by fixing the response-type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69712620/5730279), I would like to share some practical advice on JSON-conversion especially when implementing web-API [facades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) like your `Client` / `Server` classes:

1. **pure-functions** with parameters make code more testable: `send(request)`
2. content-conversion (from/into formats, like JSON) is a (cross-cutting) **separate concern**: inject a reusable component like `ObjectMapper` into client and server (representation layer) to make your request/response classes format-independent

The resulting code might appeal to you as

- more readable
- easier to comprehend and debug
- less coupled
- easier to maintain and extend

### Request to response: `send` as *pure function*

Usually the responsibility of a client is to send multiple different requests. So parameterize your `send` method.

#### Design issues

Before:  No parameter but static hard-coded request. Thus not testable.

```java
public VehicleRequest sendRequest() throws Exception {
    out.println(VehicleRequest.toJSON(new VehicleRequest(2008,"Honda","Civic")));
    return VehicleRequest.fromJSON(in.readLine());
}
```

Note: the method signature `...Request sendRequest()` can be read like "output = produceInput()". This style of designing methods or functions is called [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function): it usually converts an input to a new output - it produces something, like a response.

Design issues:
Here no input can be given. The returned product or answer could be expected to be always the same. Wouldn't you like to ask different questions or send different requests. So that the expected answer depends on the given request.

#### Improve

After: Added parameter to make testable with different `request`s. Method name simplified.

```java
public VehicleResponse send(VehicleRequest request) throws Exception {
    out.println(VehicleRequest.toJSON(request));
    return VehicleResponse.fromJSON(in.readLine());
}
```

This can be called in your `main` or in a test like `response = client.send(new VehicleRequest(2008,"Honda","Civic"))`.

### Object representation: JSON-conversion as separate-concern

There are some basic representation formats like `String` that are tightly coupled to each class. In Java this *concern* is inherited from `Object` class's methods `toString()` and for some wrapper-classes like `Integer.valueOf(String s)`.

However more complex representations, especially REST- or HTTP-related like *JSON*, `XML`, `HTML`, but also binary formats are usually treated by a design principle called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Especially in web-applications (like your simplified client-server architecture) this leads to separate layers (best-practice):

- Representation layer (concern of UI, Web, Communication) .. e.g. your `Client` / `Server` classes and Jackson's `ObjectMapper` handling JSON-conversion
- Business layer (concern of Logic) .. e.g. your `Vehicle..` classes
- Persistence layer (concern of Storage, Database, etc.)

See these separate concerns illustrated as layers, e.g. in Wikipedia [Multi-tier Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) or in Robert C. Martin's [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

### Design issues

The external dependency Jackson is duplicated part of your DTO-classes like `..Request` and `..Response`. So both depend on Jackson and JSON-format.

Before: Concern of representation layer is mixed into DTO-classes, which might change along with Business layer. Now they need to change with each format, the client can support, too (strong-coupling and 2 reasons to change).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

// ..

@JsonIgnore
private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

// duplicated code, implemented similarly for both classes
public static String toJSON(VehicleRe.. vehicle) throws Exception {
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(vehicle);
}

public static VehicleRe.. fromJSON(String input) throws Exception{
    return objectMapper.readValue(input, VehicleRe.. .class);
}
```

Note: You could move this cross-cutting (used by many classes) concern into the client. This way, your (entity) classes stay independent from the format/mapping-framework and the client can be easily extended to support other formats (like XML) in the future.

### Improve

After: In REST formats are concern of the representation layer. The client is responsible of content-negotiation and conversion.

```java
class Client {
   private final ObjectMapper mapper;

   // Mapper can be injected as dependency, configurable from ouside
   public Client(ObjectMapper mapper) {
       this.mapper = mapper;
       // optional remaining initialization, could add ip, port, etc.
   }

   public VehicleResponse send(VehicleRequest vehicle) throws Exception {
       String request = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(vehicle);  // to <textual-format>

       out.println(request); // request as String (now JSON, future XML)
       String response = in.readLine(); // request as String (now JSON, future XML)
       
       return objectMapper.readValue(response); // from <textual-format>
   }
}
```

This way you can in your main-method simply create a special XML-capable client by configuring like
`Client xmlClient = new Client(new XmlMapper())` or use as-is (with JSON as content-exchange format): `Client client = new Client(new ObjectMapper())`.

---

For your CS-course and homework this might be too much and over-engineering.

However in "real code", as seen in professional web-frameworks like `Spring`, this is good or best-practice and contributes to extensible and maintainable software, see [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) .